# How to chronologically use Javascript code to alter image size

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Im currently working on a small HTML5 game. Now I am busy with making the small car shrink in size when it reaches the horizon (on the road) and go back to original size when it drives back towards 'us'.

I am pretty new to javascript, that is why I started making this small game, I figured what better way to learn, right?

So this is what I have (within a canvas):

```
var render = function () {
    if (bgReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
    }

    if (carReady) {
        //ctx.drawImage(carImage, car.x, car.y);

         ctx.drawImage(carImage, car.x, car.y, (carImage.width /100 * 50),(carImage.height / 100 * 50));

    }
    };
```

What I want to say is, that the size only should be altered when car.y gets smaller. However I am not really sure about where to place it, in order to not get a chronological-error.

What I am trying to get is:

```
ctx.drawImage(carImage, car.x, car.y, (carImage.width /100 * 50),(carImage.height / 100 * 50));

if(car.y++){
car.Image.width /i * 50  && carImage.height /i * 50}
```

> With the variable 'i' increasing as car.y increases.

I hope someone can point me into the right direction.

Mieer

**EDIT**:

```
// Handle keyboard controls
var keysDown = {};

addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);

addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
}, false);

// Reset the game when the player catches a fuel
    var reset = function () {
    car.x = canvas.width / 3;
    car.y = canvas.height / 1.2;


    // Throw the fuel somewhere on the screen randomly [lengte(math random) keer breedte voor een random plaat in de oppervlakte)]
    //fuel.x = 300 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 700));   -old

    fuel.y = 500 + (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 550));


    //The left-most x coordinate for each y coordinate,
    //The road-width for each y coordinate.

    var left_most_x = 10 + ((500-10)/1000) * fuel.y
    var road_width = 500 - ((500-30)/1000) * fuel.y

    fuel.x = left_most_x + (Math.random() * road_width)

};

// Update game objects
var update = function (modifier) {
    if (38 in keysDown) { // Player holding up
        car.y -= car.speed * modifier;
    }
    if (40 in keysDown) { // Player holding down
        car.y += car.speed * modifier;
    }
    if (37 in keysDown) { // Player holding left
        car.x -= car.speed * modifier;
    }
    if (39 in keysDown) { // Player holding right
        car.x += car.speed * modifier;
    }

    // Are they touching?
    if (
        car.x <= (fuel.x + 32)
        && fuel.x <= (car.x + 32)
        && car.y <= (fuel.y + 32)
        && fuel.y <= (car.y + 32)
    ) {
        ++fuelsCaught;
        reset();
    }
};
```

Comment: Well if you want to perform an action ('make car smaller') based on an event ("y gets smaller") you're going to need an event listener. Is the user dragging the car with the mouse? Pressing an arrow key? WASD?

Comment: The user is using the arrow keys! See my update please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try keeping track of the last y value:

```
var lastY = 0;

var render = function () {

    if (bgReady) 
        ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);    

    if (carReady) 
        ctx.drawImage(carImage, car.x, car.y, (carImage.width / 100 * 50), (carImage.height / 100 * 50));    

    var deltaY = car.y - lastY;

    carImage.width = carImage.width - deltaY;
    carImage.height = carImage.height - deltaY;

    lastY = car.y;
};
```

Comment: It worked, I altered it a bit in order to get a more logical increment of the size, but it works to a satisfactory degree.